# What paths should I use to install cross-compiled packages to?

Tags: cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I have installed a MinGW-W64 into `$HOME/mingw32`:

```
~$ ls -l mingw32
insgesamt 32
drwxr-xr-x  2 js js 4096 16. Aug 16:41 bin
drwxr-xr-x 10 js js 4096 26. Nov 14:49 i686-w64-mingw32
drwxr-xr-x  2 js js 4096 16. Aug 16:28 include
drwxr-xr-x  3 js js 4096 16. Aug 16:41 lib
drwxr-xr-x  3 js js 4096 16. Aug 16:36 libexec
drwxr-xr-x 14 js js 4096 16. Aug 16:41 licenses
drwxr-xr-x  4 js js 4096 26. Nov 15:17 QtWin32
drwxr-xr-x  6 js js 4096 16. Aug 16:41 share
~$
```

This resulted from extracting `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.7.1-2-release-linux64_rubenvb.tar.xz.tar` and installing various software cross compiled on my linux64 build system for a windows32 host. For example, `libpng`:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32 --host=i686-w64-mingw32
```

To use the installed tools, I have to add `$HOME/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/bin` to my `PATH` environment variable. However, I am relucant to do that because this binary directory contains

```
$ ls $HOME/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/bin
ar g++ gcc ld nm objcopy ranlib strip # much more
```

Hence I thought that maybe the right place for installing cross compiled packages to is `$HOME/mingw32`, such that I can omit adding `$HOME/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/bin` to my `PATH`. However, this did not work, since several `./configure` scripts failed to find headers of other packages I installed previously, when those headers were installed to `$HOME/mingw32/include`. When I installed them to `$HOME/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include`, they were found by `./configure` scripts.

Do I need to do something special to tell the cross-compiler to take `$HOME/mingw32/include` as a built-in include path? Much like `/usr/include` is built-in for the native compiler, I mean.

Thus I am not sure what the correct prefix to use is. Can someone please explain the correct path and the exact meaning of `$HOME/mingw32/` and `$HOME/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32`?

Answer (score 0):

With Cygwin MinGW-w64 is installed to `/usr`, for example

```
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
```

So I would recommend using this, or maybe `/usr/local`. As far as include goes, you can figure the correct path like this

```
$ touch a.c

$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -v a.c |& awk '/#include/,/End/'
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.5.3/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.5.3/include-fixed
 /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include
End of search list.
```

[**source**](http://mingw.org/wiki/IncludePathHOWTO)